# Crash when dynamically change LayoutManager to FlexboxLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I have to use both `LinearLayoutManager` or `FlexbotLayoutManager` depends on childs size in RecyclerView.

When I change `LinearLayoutManager` to `FlexbotLayoutManager` dynamically like:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = 
            FlexibleFlexboxLayoutManager(context).apply {
                    flexWrap = FlexWrap.NOWRAP
                    flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
            }
```

I face that error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   com.google.android.flexbox.FlexItem
>           at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxHelper.calculateFlexLines(FlexboxHelper.java:439)
>           at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxHelper.calculateHorizontalFlexLines(FlexboxHelper.java:243)
>           at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager.updateFlexLines(FlexboxLayoutManager.java:955)
>           at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(FlexboxLayoutManager.java:731)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `FlexboxLayoutManager` overrides only `generateLayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs)` but does not override `generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp)`

So solution is implementing that method:

```
class SafeFlexboxLayoutManager : FlexboxLayoutManager {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, flexDirection: Int) : super(context, flexDirection)

    constructor(context: Context, flexDirection: Int, flexWrap: Int) : super(context, flexDirection, flexWrap)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr,
        defStyleRes
    )

    override fun generateLayoutParams(lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams(lp)
    }
}
```